# can't connect to ec2 from some networks

Tags: amazon-ec2, networking

My EC2 instance does not answer pings or requests from a certain network, while it does answer pings from other ones. This causes my webapp to crash for that network. The particular network where it's failing right now is an open public network at a large university. The transfer protocol is HTTP going to port 3000. What could be the problem, and how can I resolve it?

I'm pretty new to server administration, so if I should provide any other details, I would be glad to.

Edit:
My security groups:

```
TCP to port 3000 (Node.js) from everywhere  
TCP to port 22 (SSH) from my working IP  
TCP to port 80 (HTTP) from everywhere  
TCP to port 443 (HTTPS) from everywhere  
All ICMP from everywhere
```

All outbound traffic is allowed.

Comment: Show traceroute from a good network, and traceroute from a bad network?

Comment: The SGs look ok. My answer below still stands.

Comment: Traceroute from university network chokes up after two hops. I guess we're opening a ticket with them, then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've verified that:

1. Your security groups are not blocking these
2. You don't have iptables rules that would be blocking anything

the only thing you can do is open up a ticket with AWS support. Additionally, you should talk with the IT department of this University to see if they might be blocking your traffic.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will include my security groups in the question.